# How do I assign an image to external links?

Tags: html, image, linkedin-api

Bit of a silly question but when I'm linking my portfolio to external sites like Linkedin, a randomly selected image shows up. How do I change the source for my image so that I can use my logo as the image shown instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can just include your logo as a source to the image in your source code:

```html
<img src="url-to-your-logo" alt="alternative text">
```

Comment: I have my logo in the source code already: `<a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="logo_trans.png" alt="logo">` - the image it selected is one in an element further down the page

Comment: did you close your anchor tag with </a>? (in the code above, you didn't). It should be `<a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="logo_trans.png" alt="logo"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a reference to the image you want to display in a `meta` tag with a `property="og:image"` attribute.

Such meta tags control which information will be displayed when sharing your link:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Of My Site">
<meta property="og:description" content="This description will appear below the title in a smaller font.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.example.com/show-this-instead-of-linkedin-logo.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.example.com">
```

You can check [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/) for more information.